# Refactoring functions to make more generic

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have the following code copy/pasted multiple times. The values that change are the string literals ("TabStates" changes to "ContentStates" etc..) and the value of the dictionary (RadTabSetting -> ContentSetting).

```
public static SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting> GetTabStates()
{
    SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting> _tabStates = new SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting>();

    if (!object.Equals(DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.GetSession("TabStates"), null))
    {
        _tabStates = DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.GetSession("TabStates") as SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting>;
    }
    else
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_tabStates.GetType());

        string data = DashoardDatabaseRepository.Instance.GetWebLayoutData("TabStates");

        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) )
        {
            byte[] dataAsArray = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dataAsArray);
            _tabStates = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting>;
            }
            DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.SetSession("TabStates", _tabStates);
        }

        return _tabStates;
    }

    public static void SetTabStates(SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting> tabStates)
    {
        DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.SetSession("TabStates", tabStates);
        DashboardDatabaseRepository.Instance.SaveToDatabase("TabStates", tabStates);
    }
```

I'm not looking for an answer, just curious what I should read about to learn how to rewrite this. I'm sure it's simple enough, just not sure what it's called. Is it just function templating?

```
    public static T GetStates<T>() where T: new()
    {
        T _states = new T();//(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        string stateName = StateDictionary.GetStateName(typeof(T));

        if (!object.Equals(DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.GetSession(stateName), null))
        {
            _states = (T)DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.GetSession(stateName);

            //Work-Around
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(_states.GetType());
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, _states);
            string data = System.Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            string otherData = DashboardDatabaseRepository.Instance.GetWebLayoutData(stateName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_states.GetType());
                byte[] dataAsArray = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dataAsArray);

                _states = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            //Work-Around
        }
        else
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_states.GetType());

            string data = DashboardDatabaseRepository.Instance.GetWebLayoutData(stateName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                byte[] dataAsArray = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dataAsArray);
                _states = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.SetSession(stateName, _states);
        }

        return _states;
    }

    public static void SetStates<T>(T states) where T: new()
    {
        string stateName = StateDictionary.GetStateName(typeof(T));

        DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.SetSession(stateName, states);
        DashboardDatabaseRepository.Instance.SaveToDatabase(stateName);
    }

static class StateDictionary
{   
    //TODO: Might (should?) be able to redo this polymorphically.
    static IDictionary<Type, string> _stateDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, string>
    {
        {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting>), "TabStates"},
        {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadDockContentSetting>), "ContentStates"},
        {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadPaneSetting>), "PaneStates"},
        {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadDockSetting>), "DockStates"},
        {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadDockZoneSetting>), "DockZoneStates"},
        {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadSplitterSetting>), "SplitterStates"},
        {typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, RadSplitBarSetting>), "SplitBarStates"},
        {typeof(KnownGlobalSettings), "GlobalSettings"},
    };

    public static string GetStateName(Type type)
    {
        string stateName = string.Empty;

        if (_stateDictionary.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            stateName = _stateDictionary[type];
        }

        return stateName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple comments: instead of Activator.CreateInstance I would recommend adding a new() constraint to your type parameter, so you can simply say new T(), which IMO is cleaner

Comment: Also, each time DetermineStateName is called, you build your lookup table anew.  I would build it once in a **static constructor** (simple to do, just google it real quick) and then reference that going forward.  Usually you want to avoid checking the type of an object, preferring to use polymorphism instead (virtual methods that are overridden), but in this case I'm guessing you can't modify or even create partial classes from all your RadXXX classes (Telerik?)

Comment: Implemented static constructors and replaced Activator.CreateInstance with something more intuitive. I'll save refactoring to more polymorphic code for another day. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, but what I said was that you probably could *not* refactor towards polymorphism, since I'm assuming you don't have control over your RadXXX classes.  If you do in fact have control over them, then sure, refactor when you have some time

Comment: I do have control over them. Just named poorly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Martin Fowler's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) is the standard source for refactoring.

But for your specific example, just create a new method that takes in parameters representing the things that change in your example.  So you'll want a string parameter for your "TabStates" or "ContentStates" value, and another representing your Value for Key ContentSetting in your dictionary.

Does that make sense?  Am I understanding your question fully?

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you want to use generics.  Something like this should get you going:

```
public static Dictionary<string, T> GetTabStates<T>()
```

Just note that you won't be able to do much with your type T unless you add some generic constraints.

If you want to create a new instance of T, then you would need

```
public static Dictionary<string, T> GetTabStates<T>() where T : new() {
```

And if you want to access actual properties on an instance of T, then hopefully all possible values for T will implement some sort of interface, in which case you would say:

```
public interface IFoo {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public static Dictionary<string, T> GetTabStates<T>() where T : new(), IFoo {
   T Tval = new T();
   Tval.Id = 1;
   //etc
```

Comment: The string part is fine. Each Get method would return a different type of object, though. GetTabStates returns SerializableDictionary<string, RadTabSetting>, but GetContentStates returns SerializableDictionary<string, ContentSetting>. The logic performed to get to returning this object is the same, however.

Comment: The "TabStates" vs. "ContentStates" choice would be a function parameter, but the RadTabSetting vs. ContentSetting choice would be a generic parameter.